# How to update data that has its primary key generated automatically

Tags: sql, vb.net

The primary key of the table is generated automatically using the Is Identity and I want to update based on the primary key. There is certainly something wrong with the following code, so I'd like someone to modify it for me. Thanks in advance.

```
     Try
        Dim qry As String
        qry = "Update StudentDetails.Programmes set Programme=@Programme,Form=@Form,AcademicYear=@AcademicYear,Class=@Class where ID=ID"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qry, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Programme", txtProgramme.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Form", txtForm.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AcademicYear", txtAcademicYear.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Class", txtClass.Text))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Record succesfully updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            showgrid()
        End If
        txtProgramme.Focus()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

'PS: The code below shows how the data is inserted. Is Identity is set to Yes in the database. The works perfectly. The problem the code I want corrected is the update command above.

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into StudentDetails.programmes(Programme,Form,AcademicYear,Class) values(@Programme,@Form,@AcademicYear,@Class)", cn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Programme", txtProgramme.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Form", txtForm.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicYear", txtAcademicYear.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", txtClass.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Comment: You show us the update-command, but where is your insert-command and why don't you know the pk? Btw, use parameters to prevent sql-injection.

Comment: +1 to use parameters ! between if u have a column 'ID' which is unqiue . Why do you generate the primary key at all.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that just now.

Comment: The primary key is inserted automatically during saving. Anyway, I'm now using parameters and I still have the same old problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an self-explanatory example on how to retrieve new identity values with ADO.NET:

```
Using con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CC_ConnectionString)
    Dim newID As Int32
    Using insertCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test(Value)VALUES(@Value);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)", con)
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "Value1")
        con.Open()
        newID = DirectCast(insertCommand.ExecuteScalar, Int32)
    End Using

    If newID <> 0 Then
        Using updateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE TEST SET Value='Value1.1' WHERE idTest=@idTest", con)
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idTest", newID)
            If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
            Dim updatedRecordCount = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
        End Using
    End If
End Using
```

The 2 important parts are:

```
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
```

which will return the new identity value

```
DirectCast(insertCommand.ExecuteScalar, Int32)
```

which will return the new Identity column value if a new row was inserted, 0 on failure.

Using parameters will prevent [SQL-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx).

- [SCOPE_IDENITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)
- [ExceuteScalar-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)
- [Commands and Parameters in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953.aspx)

Comment: You ended up explaining the self-explanatory.  :-)

Comment: Oh please I still don't get the meaning of your code. Just try to edit mine for me.

Comment: @Akaglo: What part do you not understand? Does your insert work now? I think i've added all you need to get it working, so maybe you need to invest some time to drill down on the links provided in my answer.

Comment: Please my insert command which is executed separately always works perfectly to insert the primary key automatically since the Is Identity in the database is set to Yes. Check out my save command above.

Comment: I still don't understand the requirement 100%. Your question was how to retrieve the identity value of inserted records. I've shown you the way, but the code above does not contain my approach. So is your question how to change the insert so that it returns the new ID or is it how to change your update stament so that it works? You haven't even said what does not work or what exception do you get. Sorry, i must go to bed now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling it what the ID is to match.

& "' where ID=ID"

to

& "' where ID='" & txtID.Text & "'"

and follow Tim's suggestion as well.

Comment: Please since the ID is inserted automatically, there is no control like txtID.Text on the form. I mean txtID.Text doesn't exist on the form at all.

Comment: You cannot run this UPDATE without knowing the ID of the record that you want to update!  Your INSERT should return the new ID in an Output parameter that you then use in your UPDATE.  You will need to create an ID parameter in your update.  This is a very, very basic concept and, I suggest that you follow the links @Tim Schmelter posted in his answer and work through it.